# the simplest and quickest way to build a wxPython GUI

Tags: wxpython

I'm a C++ developer. I use Python mainly for helpers, testers etc., until now only in command line. Recently I needed to create a very small GUI application with two text boxes and one OK button. What would be the simplest and quickest way to code it in wx?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, it would be to just do it by hand and put the widgets in one or two BoxSizers. For others, they might choose to use XRC, Boa Constructor, wxGlade or wxFormBuilder instead. There's a decent example here:

http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2008/05/18/a-wxpython-sizers-tutorial/

It has a more complex example than you need, but it should give you the general idea.